# Using Python to create a dictionary with setters and getters

Tags: python

I have a class method to create a dictionary. I set and get these values like this:

```
 class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = {}


    def set_config_key(self, key, value):
        self.config[key] = value

    def _get_config_value(self, key):
       return self.config[key]
```

In Python 2.7 is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use attribute access with [the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) instead:

```
class Test(object):
    config = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = {}

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self.config is None:
            # set config directly
            super(Test, self).__setattr__(key, value)
            return
        self.config[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
       return self.config[key]
```

This translates `Test().foo` into `Test().config['foo']`.

Demo:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.foo = 'bar'
>>> t.foo
'bar'
>>> t.config
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

You could also map this directly to the object `__dict__`, instead of `self.config`; if you subclass `dict` you get an object that is both a mapping and takes arbitrary attributes:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Demo:

```
>>> class AttrDict(dict):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
...         super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
...         self.__dict__ = self
... 
>>> foo = AttrDict()
>>> foo.bar = 'baz'
>>> foo
{'bar': 'baz'}
>>> foo.bar
'baz'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass dictionary, and have the same behavior that a dict would in a very clean way:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

>>> md = MyDict()
>>> md
{}
>>> md.foo = 1
>>> md
{'foo': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like redundant code. You don't gain encapsulation/protection from this code.
If your goal is to add some sort of processing to key and value before reading the list then this *works*. However, to make your code more readable you would be better off overloading **getitem** and **setitem** (the builtin array operators) (among others like **delitem**)

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = {}


    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Do some processing here
        self.config[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Do some processing here
        return self.config[key]
```

This enables you to do the following in your code:

```
t = Test()
t['foo'] = 'bar'
print(t['foo']) # prints 'bar'
```

Until you add some extra code to this, it will behave like a normal dictionary as far as getting and setting values goes.